# Pass function as parameter

Tags: c#, function, generics, caching, parameters

I have a function:

```
private static PrivateMessage GetPM()
{
    using (var db = new DBContext())
    {
        var q = CompiledQueries.GetPMByID(db, messageID);
        if (q == null) return null;
        return new PrivateMessage(q);
    }
}
```

I wish to pass this function as a parameter:

```
var pm = cacheObj.SetIfNotExists(GetPM);
```

Where `SetIfNotExists` is defined as:

```
public T SetIfNotExists<T>(Func<T> getCachableObjectFunction)
```

What do I need to modify so that I can pass `messageID` as a parameter in `GetPM()`?  EG:

```
private static PrivateMessage GetPM(int messageID)
```

Comment: var pm = cacheObj.SetIfNotExists(() => GetPM(1)); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap and typecast your output is the easiest way.

```
var pm = cacheObj.SetIfNotExists(() => GetPM(1));
```

And change `GetPM` header to:

```
private static PrivateMessage GetPM(int messageID)
```

Comment: Perfect thank you!  Answers my next question of how to do it for functions with different parameter inputs as well!  Just checking, passing it in this way won't invoke it will it?

Comment: You're right, it doesn't but the answer lets you pass any number of parameters in the `GetPM()` method.

Comment: @TomGullen Probably should have just given your own answer instead, but this is correct now.